# Spark --Error :type mismatch; found : (Int, String) required: TraversableOnce[?]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark programming and scala and I am not able to understand the difference between map and flatMap. While using flatMap, why is "Option" used in method is working fine

```
def parseNames(line: String) : Option[(Int,String)]  = {
  var fields = line.split('\"')
  if (fields.length >1) {
    return Some(fields(0).trim().toInt,fields(1) )
  }
  else {
    return None
  }
}
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]","DemoHero")
  val txt= sc.textFile("../marvel-names1.txt")  
  val rdd = txt.flatMap(parseNames)
```

but without "Option", an error is coming:

```
def parseNames(line: String) : (Int, String)  = {
  var fields = line.split('\"')    
  (fields(0).trim().toInt,fields(1) )
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]","DemoHero")   
  val txt= sc.textFile("../marvel-names1.txt")  
  val rdd = txt.flatMap(parseNames)
```

As per my understanding, flatmap make Rdd in to collection for String/Int Rdd. I was thinking that in this case both should work without any error. Please let me know where I am making the mistake.

Comment: Why your second code snippet doesn't work should be obvious. Why the first snippet works: that's the mystery, because `Option` does not extend `TraversableOnce`.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: There is an implicit conversion from `Option` to `Iterable`, this is why your first 
`flatMap` does not fail.

---

From the [inheritance hierarchy of `Option`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.10/index.html#scala.Option) it is not at all clear why RDD's [`flatMap`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L378) that expects an
argument with `TraversableOnce` in return type would accept a function that returns an `Option`, because
`Option` does not extend `TraversableOnce`.

However, if you print the desugared code generated by your `flatMap`, the following synthetic function definition appears:

```
@SerialVersionUID(value = 0) final <synthetic> class anonfun$1 extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1 with Serializable {
  final def apply(line: String): Iterable = scala.this.Option.option2Iterable(org.example.ClassName.parseNames$1(line));
  final <bridge> <artifact> def apply(v1: Object): Object = anonfun$1.this.apply(v1.$asInstanceOf[String]());
  def <init>(): <$anon: Function1> = {
    anonfun$1.super.<init>();
    ()
  }
}
```

The details are not that important, it's some thing that takes a `line: String` and returns an `Iterable`.
What's interesting is the `Option.option2Iterable` part.

This is an implicit conversion [defined directly on Option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.10/index.html#scala.Option$),
it quietly converts options into `Iterable`, and `Iterable` is a special case of `TraversableOnce`.

This is how the compiler can sneak in the `option2Iterable` into a synthetic `Function`-definition
that mediates between your method and the invocation of `flatMap`. Now you have an argument of
type `String => Iterable[(Int, String)]`, so the `flatMap` compiles fine.

Note that it wouldn't work without a synthetic `Function`-instance that wraps your method. If you declared `parseNames` like this:

```
def parseNames: String => Option[(Int,String)] = { line =>
```

this would be a straightforward compiler error.

---

Your second code snippet shouldn't compile, and luckily, it indeed doesn't: pairs are not `Traversable`, so
`flatMap` does not accept a `parseNames(line: String) : (Int, String)` as argument. What you want to use here is 
`map`, because you want to *map* each string to exactly one pair of `(Int, String)`.

The `flatMap` is for a different use case: it's for converting each element in your original collection into 
another collection, and then flattening out all resulting collections into a single collection, so, for example,

```
sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3)).flatMap{ x => List(x, x*x, x*x*x) }
```

would first produce a `TraversableOnce` for each `x`:

```
List(1,1,1)
List(2,4,8)
List(3,9,27)
```

and then glue them all together, so that you would obtain an RDD with entries

```
1,1,1,2,4,8,3,9,27
```

It works with `Option` in the same way, because "morally" it is something like a list with 0-to-1 elements, even though it doesn't say that explicitly in its inheritance hierarchy.

---

Notice about the formulation "should not compile": whenever I write that (your code, or some other code) "should not compile", I don't mean that I *generally* wish that you had compile errors in your code. What I do mean is that *if* there is some problem in the code, the compiler should produce a clear error message as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
def parseNames (line: String): Option[(Int,String)]  = {
  var fields = line.split('\"')
  if (fields.length > 1) {
    Some (fields(0).trim ().toInt, fields(1))
  }
  else {
    None
  }
}
```

(removed the noisy "return")

Well, when is `None` returned? If fields.length is not > 1. If there aren't at least 2 fields (fields(0) and fields(1)), `fields(0).trim().toInt` might succeed, but `fields(1)` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

`flatMap` would require *iterables* as the *return type* of the function being called. Because `flatMap` would iterate through each element of *iterable* and return each element flattened.

In your first `parseNames` function, `Option[(Int, String)]` is returned which is a *container* and it can operate like an *iterable* due to use of implicit functions. So `flatMap` worked.

But in your second `parseNames`, `Tuple2[Int, String]` is returned which is **not an iterable**. As `Tuple2` cannot be iterated but the elements can be get by using `_1` and `_2`. So the `flatMap` showed you compilation error .

I hope the explanation is clear.

The second `parseNames` would have worked if you return `Array` as

```
def parseNames(line: String) : Array[(Int, String)]  = {
  var fields = line.split('\"')

  Array((fields(0).trim().toInt,fields(1)))
}
```

or `List` as

```
def parseNames(line: String) : List[(Int, String)]  = {
  var fields = line.split('\"')

  List((fields(0).trim().toInt,fields(1)))
}
```

or `Seq` as

```
def parseNames(line: String) : Seq[(Int, String)]  = {
  var fields = line.split('\"')

  Seq((fields(0).trim().toInt,fields(1)))
}
```

Because all of them are *iterables* as `Option` is.

Comment: `Option[(Int, String)]` is not an Iterable.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin thanks for the correction. I have updated my answer :) I hope its good now

Comment: Well, yeah... except that `Container` is not even a trait, and the `flatMap` quite clearly states that it expects something that returns `TraversableOnce`, but `Option` is also not a subclass `TraversableOnce`. There is a nasty implicit conversion story going on under the hood, see the gory details in my answer.

Comment: Yeah I saw that @AndreyTyukin :)